# Unable to run flutter doctor, flutter pub get etc

Tags: flutter

I managed to install flutter with the welcome to flutter screen, and I can run flutter --version.
But whenever I try to run flutter doctor, flutter clean, flutter pub get etc it keeps showing:

" Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_tools..." with a long loading time.

Then in red: "Got socket error trying to find package node_preamble at https://pub.dartlang.org."

Followed by "pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second... Running "flutter pub get" in flutter _tools..." and the cycle repeats.

This is to set flutter up on a MacOS device, and I haven't even started migrating the file from my Windows device.

Answer (score -1):

Goto your system properties tab, at advanced tab, click on user profile settings, then change the default profile to the pc user profile name. Example as the photos upload.After that go back to your cmd and try the flutter doctor code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dMgL.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biDVU.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCl8l.jpg)

Comment: Can you explain it clearly and use pictures as just with solution not all screen.